# eclipse can't open my .java files..?

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-juno

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException (Probably The best way of describing an exception)..
```

The above error shows up when I try to open my .java file... it just does't show up in my editor.. I'm stuck here.. I use eclipse juno...

This is what I did..

1. I deleted my project from eclipse(not the project in disk), I had to do this since eclipse could never refresh its work space after adding a file.. it just could't find it..
2. Imported the project from disk space.

Thats it..

Comment: Did you try to refresh your workspace?

Comment: yeah i did.. cleaning, refreshing..and so on

Comment: search for the file called `.snap` and delete it, try to start eclipse again after that...

Comment: @WarrenFaith .. restarting eclipse fixed it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about this but you can try. Copy your project in new place. restart your eclipse with new workspace and import your project. And just cross check is your project have all necessary files.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else with the same problem, restart Eclipse and try again. Worked for the OP and for me.